# Linux Character device: userspace (cat) does not stop reading

Tags: linux-kernel

I made a simple character device, and created a node for communicating with it. When I `cat /dev/mychrdev`, it userspace invokes my character device's read function over and over again. The relevant code is:

```
static ssize_t useless_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp) {
    int ret, read_count;

    read_count = sprintf(message, "Major number: %d\n", MAJOR(useless_chr_dev->cdev_num));

    ret = copy_to_user(buff, message, read_count);

    if (ret == 0) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "userspace read success");
            return read_count;
    } else
            return -EFAULT;
}
```

After I initiate a read from the terminal, dmesg is filled with:

```
[ 8966.299554] userspace read success
```

and cat is giving out lots of

```
Major number: 242
Major number: 242
Major number: 242
Major number: 242
```

Why isnt it stopping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` is not about calling your read function once. `cat` will keep calling the read function unless you return a 0 (i.e no more bytes to read).

Comment: Glad to know there is nothing wrong in my code! Thank you!